# Where did the Black boxes come from?

Tags: battletech

In Battletech Davion-Liao war just before the Clan invasion Davion forces faced a ComStar interdiction. But they sill mannaged to communicate by using "pony express" and black boxes.

**Who invented these black boxes?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The superluminal fax machines were designed by the Star League Defense Force Communications Command between 2572 and 2580.

A complete answer can be found at the massive Sarna archives, complete with source attribution and large amounts of fluff - [Sarna - Black Box](http://www.sarna.net/wiki/Black_Box)

If you are not aware, Sarna is the "go-to" source for all Battletech information!

Comment: I knew of Sarna but taught it was only as a reference to the MMO MechWarrior Online and its mechs. ty for this find.

Comment: @Cherubel One could spend days soaking up the canon fluff from there, still, the fate of Clan Wolverine remains unsolved.

Comment: hmmm... wasn't that kind of unveiled at the end of the "Dark Age" novels? or was that another Clan?? I think it was the Wolverines or diamond sharks... but I read those books back in the early 2000s so I might be very wrong.

Comment: @Cherubel if it was, I can't find any canon record of it anywhere. The novel *Betrayal of Ideals* by Blain lee Pardoe details the escape of Clan Wolverine from Clan Space, but not anything after or up to the Minnesota Tribe appearance. Everything else is "canon rumor".

Comment: Ahhh... I Sranaed it! :-)  I was thinking of the Fidelis!! They were best of the best!! By the end of the Books from the Dark Age era we learned that they were Clan Smoke Jaguar remnants. They were released from their oath (that they made to Devlin Stone) by Excharch Levin. Also in the Beginning when the Fidelis was introduced some speculated that it was Clan Wolwerine. That tricked me I think.